# Keep screen on in external applications

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, wakelock

I want to keep the screen on for the duration of my activity's lifecycle. We'll call this Activity A. I do so by setting

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

in the xml. This works perfectly on most screens. However, Activity A launches Activity B, which is used in other parts of the app. Is there a way to force Activity B to keep the screen on when launched from Activity A? I've read that I should avoid using wake lock; I'm curious what others' opinions are on this.

Comment: Have Activity B also use `android:keepScreenOn="true"`.

Comment: Activity B is being used elsewhere in my app. I only want to keep the screen on when it's being launched from Activity A. Wouldn't changing that make it so Activity B always keeps screen on even if it's launched from Activity C or elsewhere?

Comment: Ah, OK, now I'm getting it! Sorry, I'm a bit slow today. :-( The answer, to use `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it programmatically with:

```java
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

If you only want Activity B to keep the screen on when it's launched from Activity A  you can achieve it like this:

When A launches B, send an extra value on the intent, On B, onCreate() check if there is a value sent and only if it founds something it's because came from A.

```java
    public class ActivityB extends Activity {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) 
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);    
      }
    }
```